# Wrapping or grouping of elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have paragraphs and these are not arranged or grouped.
Now, I want to group with a class `grouped`

### HTML

```
<p>Para 1</p>
<p>Para 2</p>
<div class="line"></div>
<p>Para 3</p>
<p>Para 4</p>
<p>Para 5</p>
```

### Desired Result

```
<div class="grouped">
    <p>Para 1</p>
    <p>Para 2</p>
</div>

<div class="line"></div>

<div class="grouped">
    <p>Para 3</p>
    <p>Para 4</p>
    <p>Para 5</p>
</div>
```

I know `wrapAll` is function can help this but, it grouped all `p` in same and one element `grouped` and 
I need it in different `grouped` elements

### JSFiddle

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6a87E/)

### Note

`p` may be more than listed above in each segment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this demo [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46LXx/2/). Iterate over $("p") and group them.

```
$("p").each(function(ix,el){
   if($(el).next().is('.line')) - go to next group
   else add to current
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate, and check if the element is already wrapped, if not use nextUntil to get the collection of paragraphs and wrap them

```
$('p').each(function() {
    if ( ! $(this).closest('.grouped').length) 
        $(this).nextUntil('div').addBack().wrapAll("<div class='grouped' />");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6a87E/4/)

Comment: This is real jQuery fu, will delete my answer, am just a learning guy so this was a good learning :D +1

Answer (score 0):

This will handle multiple `.line` between `p` tags

```
var last = $(".line").length;
var divGroup = '<div class="grouped"/>';
$(".line").each(function(i,e){
    var segment1 = $(this).prevAll("p:not(.grouped)");
    $(segment1.get().reverse()).wrapAll(divGroup);
    if( i == last-1){
        $(this).nextAll("p:not(.grouped)").wrapAll(divGroup);
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/6a87E/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple `while` loop:

```
var $p = $('p').parent();

while($p.children('p').length) {
      $p.children('p:first')
        .nextUntil('.line')
        .addBack()
        .wrapAll('<div class="grouped"/>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LGhND/